# 'App not installed' error when installing release APK

Tags: android, react-native

I've followed the following steps for keystore configs:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

When I try to install APK file in a Xiaomi Mi5s (Android 6.0) device, it gives "App not installed" error. There is no problem in debug mode.

Application also crashing immediately when running:

`react-native run-android --variant=release`

`build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 300000
        versionName "3.0.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                        onesignal_app_id: "341c3f97-4e33-49b5-91c6-d79f3e1ad372",
                                        onesignal_google_project_number: "438620944422"]
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was (Xiaomi Mi5s):

- From Developer Options Enabled MUII Optimization (Reboot)
- From Developer Options Disabled MUII Optimization (Reboot)

Now I can install release versions of APK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall all other versions of the app before installing the release apk. Please make sure that the app is not installed for another user either (We had that problem with the Nexus 5 too). To uninstall the app for all users just open the App settings and select uninstall for all users instead of just dragging it up.

Comment: My phone's (Xiaomi Mi5s) operating system is customized (MIUI) and it doesn't have that option when deleting app from settings.

Comment: You can uninstall app via __adb__ too, connect your device with adb then write in terminal `adb uninstall <app_package_name>`